# Does connecting to Alljoyn disconnect wifi

Tags: android-wifi, alljoyn

I came across few WiFi based sharing applications which disconnect my phone's Internet connection. I was wondering if connecting and communicating using Alljoyn has the same effect.

Does it disconnect?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Alljoyn is just a protocol which works over WiFi. (Or in some cases Bluetooth, but WiFi or Ethernet are the normal transports for Alljoyn.)